# Search API isn't returning results with words in the title

Tags: views, search

I just installed search api and setup a server and index. Then I setup a Views page and exposed the search filter option. Searching all fields work, but for some reason its not searching the title. What could be the issue? I tried turning all fields off on the index and just left the title field option and its still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to turn on the setting *Search on parts of a word* on the Server's page in order to get it to work. Now it searches titles. I'm not sure why it doesnt search titles with that unchecked.

[image]